# Incorrect answer in dll import in Python

Tags: python, import

In my Python script I'm importing a dll written in VB.NET.
I'm calling a function of initialisation in my script. It takes 2 arguments: a path to XML file and a string. It returns an integer - 0 for success, else error. The second argument is passed by reference. So if success, it will get updated with success message. Otherwise, get updated with error message.

When my script receives the integer, I should print the message in the second variable. I'm not able to do that.

Comment: Is this really that urgent? End of the world if the Python script doesn't work?

Comment: @Kezzer: Check the poster's history of questions.  They're all urgent.  And they almost never include a code sample.  Most of them deserve the [plzsendtehcodez] tag.

Comment: My guess is that the deadline for his homework is near.

Answer (score 3):

Python strings are immutable. There is no way the string can be changed inside the function.

So what you really want is to pass a *char buffer* of some sort. You can create those in python using the `ctypes` module.

Please edit the question and paste a minimal snippet of the code so we can test and give more information.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not support the concept of passing a string "by reference" in the same way that VB.NET does. So it might not be possible to do this without some more work.

However, without seeing your code it's definitely not possible to tell you what's wrong.